# Configure HikariCP properties with multiple datasources

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I have defined two datasources for my spring application:

```
spring.datasource.audit.url=...
spring.datasource.audit.username=...
spring.datasource.audit.password=...
spring.datasource.audit.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.datasource.fic.url=...
spring.datasource.fic.username=...
spring.datasource.fic.password=...
spring.datasource.fic.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

For the *fic* datasource, I need a certain SQL to be executed just after the connection is created. I found the connectionInitSql property, but I cannot get Hikari to load the value.

For creating the *fic* datasource, I have the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.fic")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourcePropertiesFic() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    } 

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSourceFic() {
        return dataSourcePropertiesFic()
          .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
          .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateFic(@Qualifier("dataSourceFic") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

I also have an equivalent configuration class for the *audit* datasource.

I have added the following lines to my *application.properties*. Obviously it would fail if Hikari attempted to execute any of the sentences; also I have setup Hikari's log level to debug and it shows the connectionInitSql property to be null for both connection pools:

```
spring.datasource.fic.connectionInitSql=HOLA
spring.datasource.fic.hikari.connectionInitSql=HOLA
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionInitSql=HOLA
```

How could I pass that *connectionInitSql* to Hikari, only for the *uip* datasource?

I am using SpringBoot 3.0.4 with HikariCP 5.0.1

Comment: `spring.datasource.fic.hikari.connectionInitSql` should work, however you are missing an `@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.fic.hikari")` on your `dataSourceFix()` bean method. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring.datasource.fic.hikari.connectionInitSql` should work.
However you are missing an `@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.fic.hikari")` on your `dataSourceFix()` bean method!

This is also explained/shown in [the Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources). The first is to create the generic properties, the second is for binding the datasource specific properties to the implementation.